# Excel VBA: Refering to column indexes in Worksheet.Cells()

Tags: vba, excel

I realise this topic has been raised numerous times in different variants, but I still need a little help to get along.

I have a macro-enabled spreadsheet (.xlsm) in Excel 2016.

I have an old Sub which uses the call

```
wsList.Cells(6, "B").Value
```

multiple times to refer to data in different columns. wsList is a worksheet object in the workbook.

To avoid going through all these calls each time the column order changes, I tried to define the column letter indexes in the top of the sub like

```
Dim CollEmployeeEmail As String  
...  
CollEmployeeEmail = Chr(34) & "B" & Chr(34)
...
wsList.Cells(6, CollEmployeeEmail).Value
```

But this gives me a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch error.

Now, I realise, that the Cells()-property expects Integers as row and column indexes, and that I can just translate the letter column indexes to integers (e.g. "B"=2). 
Moreover, this would suggest, since Cells(6, "B") is working and Cells(6, CollEmployeeEmail) is not, that Excel is interpreting the "B" as an integer when it encounters it in Cells() as an index. (Using CollEmployeeEmail as index results in the type mismatch error since this is a String)

This puzzles me, and I would like a confirmation, that this behavior is in fact due to an interpretation by Excel or if not, the reason for this behavior.
Perhaps also an advice to the best practice regarding this.

Thanks for your patience and understanding!

Comment: You don't need the `Chr(34)`, just the `CollEmployeeEmail = "B"`. Then your `Cells` reference should work. The reason is that `CollEmployeeEmail` is declared as a `String` already so `Cells` interprets the value that way. The other way with double-quotes exists to let `Cells` know that a string value is between them.

Comment: Hi Peter
Perfect. Thank you. Precise answer and very informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REplace `CollEmployeeEmail = Chr(34) & "B" & Chr(34)` by `CollEmployeeEmail =  "B"`

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out just use `CollEmployeeEmail = "B"`.  The reason is the double quotes around the `B` creates a string variable which equals `B`.   `CollEmployeeEmail = Chr(34) & "B" & Chr(34)` creates a string variable that equals `B` surrounded by double quotes `"B"`.

[image]

I recommend always enumerating the columns of your worksheets in a public module.    This way as you make changes to the structure of the worksheet columns, all you have to do to update all your Enums.  You will also be able to easily reference the columns by name using intellisense.

[image]

```
Public Enum OrdersColumns
    ordCustomerName = 1
    ordCount
    ordAverage
    ordSales
    ordQuantity
    ordDiscount
    ordProfit
End Enum
```

You can even setup the Enums to allow you to iterate over the. See [Chip Pearson - Enum Variable Type](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx)

```
Public Enum OrdersColumns
    [_First] = 1
    ordCustomerName = 1
    ordCount
    ordAverage
    ordSales
    ordQuantity
    ordDiscount
    ordProfit
    [_Last] = 8
End Enum
```

[image]

### Immediate Window

```
For n = OrdersColumns.[_First] to OrdersColumns.[_Last] : _
   Debug.Print Cells(1,n).Value  : _
Next

Columns(OrdersColumns.ordCount ).Select
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
Dim CollEmployeeEmail As String  
...  
CollEmployeeEmail = "B"
...
wsList.Cells(6, CollEmployeeEmail).Value
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the answers. When you write it, it seems obvious, but it certainly was not for me.

The solution was indeed to replace `CollEmployeeEmail = Chr(34) & "B" & Chr(34)` by `CollEmployeeEmail =  "B"`, removing the `Chr(34)` quotes.

@TinMan: Thanks for the very elaborate answer and the tip regarding enumeration. Very useful.